# Historical manhwa about a reincarnated white-haired female lead who was previously a powerful mage

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, reincarnation

It's about a daughter of a count (or something else) who is uninterested in life and doing nothing. She was the head of the mage tower who got betrayed by her trusted friends. She later kills them and innocent people, which leads her to being cursed by a god and reincarnated about a hundred times, before she marries a brown-haired knight (probably the male lead).

This is all I remember.

Comment: You mentioned that the main character was reincarnated about a hundred times; were they reincarnated as a the same person a hundred times, or a different person each time?

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[Hoping for My Death](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/hoping-for-my-death)***...?

> In pursuit of a natural death, Silvia reluctantly agrees to a strategic marriage. To deceive the gods, she must convincingly play the role of a married couple. "Shall we turn off the lights then?" "Why would we...?" "Don't we have to consummate our marriage on the first night?" "Why is that necessary?" Isn't my husband too conservative? Silvia, who yearns for a chance to die, and Randal, who struggles with conflicting emotions, embark on an unexpected healing romance.

In the first chapter, we're introduced to Silvia Florette, the white-haired daughter of a viscount. She's extremely lethargic, sleeping for 16 hours or more each day, but her parents love her dearly and are keen to see her married before they die. The King arranges a marriage between her and Viscount Randal Bellfort, who has light brown hair.

[image: Hoping for My Death, chapter 1, page 5 and 6.]

We subsequently learn that this is Silvia's 100th life, and that she lived her 99 past lives as a woman named Alisa.

In her first life, Alisa was a powerful sorceress who fought demons to protect her kingdom. She even learned to wield the demon's dark power against them, but her companions feared her growing strength and betrayed her, pushing her through a portal into the demon realm.

She spent years there, continuing to fight demons, but gradually turned demonic herself and ultimately attacked the human realm, killing those who betrayed her, before being slain by a Hero. She then woke up in the afterlife, where a voice told her that she'd be forced to live 99 lives trapped in a cycle of reincarnation as punishment for her sins.

After her 99th life ended, her sentence was over, and she was reincarnated as a new person (Silvia), but told not to kill herself if she didn't want to repeat her punishment.

[image: Hoping for My Death, chapter 2, page 28 and 29.]