# Manhwa in which the female lead is punished for being a tyrant in her first life with 100 tragic reincarnations

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

Specific manhwa in which the female lead was a tyrant punished with repeated reincarnations. The story begins on her 99th reincarnation and she is lazy with loving parents. She is getting married and has white hair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: I thought it was on Mangadex or Webtoons, but I can't find it there. It's probably on a fanslation site but I don't know which one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Hoping for My Death](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/hoping-for-my-death)***...?

> In pursuit of a natural death, Silvia reluctantly agrees to a strategic marriage. To deceive the gods, she must convincingly play the role of a married couple. "Shall we turn off the lights then?" "Why would we...?" "Don't we have to consummate our marriage on the first night?" "Why is that necessary?" Isn't my husband too conservative? Silvia, who yearns for a chance to die, and Randal, who struggles with conflicting emotions, embark on an unexpected healing romance.

In the first chapter, we're introduced to Silvia Florette, the white-haired, 22-year-old daughter of a viscount. She sleeps 16 hours a day, but is still lethargic when she's awake and doesn't eat much. Nonetheless, her parents love her dearly and are keen to see her married before they die. The King arranges a marriage between her and Viscount Randal Bellfort, which she accepts.

[image: Hoping for My Death, chapter 1, page 5 and 6.]

We subsequently learn that this is Silvia's 100th life, and that she lived her 99 previous lives as different people. In her first life, she was a powerful sorceress named Alisa who fought demons to protect her kingdom, but turned against her own people after they betrayed her. She was ultimately slain by a Hero and woke up in the afterlife, where a disembodied voice told her that she'd be forced to live 99 lives trapped in a cycle of reincarnation as punishment for her sins.

[image: Hoping for My Death, chapter 2, page 28 and 29.]

Comment: Possibly also the answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/277829 .